# "Is it just me or does this annoys you?" Please show me whats the mistake in this sentance

Tags: sentence

I found it on some 9gag title post and every one commented about the ugly grammar. As a non English speaking person, I can't find the problem with that sentence.

Comment: As the Help Center says [in its “How to ask a good question” section](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask):  **“Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken th
e time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!”** Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The last phrase should be

> does this annoy you?

You *do* use *annoys* in "This annoys you."
but not in "Does this annoy you?".

Also the two phrases currently don't match up. It would make more sense to say

> Is it just me, or does this annoy you too?

Comment: It's a matter of 3rd person present tense (e.g. "he annoys her") versus any other tense ("I annoy others.")

Comment: @phyrfox Ahem: *annoys* and *annoy* are the same tense: both are present tense.

Comment: @tchrist But "I annoys you" would be incorrect-- it's 1st person.

Comment: @phyrfox That’s immaterial. It is still the present tense.

Comment: @tchrist The degree matters, though. First person and second person usually do not: (1st) "I annoy her." (2nd) "You annoy her." (3rd) "She annoys them."

Comment: @phyrfox Again, it doesn’t matter: the point is that you misused the word *tense* to mean something else.

Comment: (tchrist is saying that _annoy_ and _annoys_ are different _conjugations_ rather than different tenses.)